# Pandas to_sql Error: Invalid column name 'None'

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.6

I am using pandas `to_sql()` to insert pandas's dataframe to `sql` database, using following snippet:

```
params = quote("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=%s;DATABASE=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s"%(config.server,config.database,config.user_id,config.password))
self.engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % self.params)
```

Connection is working fine.

```
dataframe.to_sql("InvoiceStandardization_InvoiceExtractTemp", con=self.engine, if_exists="append", index=False)
```

When I tried this it's showing error as :

```
[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'None'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

I have checked all columns are available in my dataframe which are in database in same order.
 What could be the possible solution?

Comment: Please print `dataframe.columns` let me see what you have there

Comment: getting list of column name like this `['intInvoiceFileId', 'vcrInvoicenumber', 'vcrInvoicedate',
       'vcrInvoiceyearmonth', 'vcrRcvparticipantcode',...`], I have list of 66 column name. i have checked, all are correct.

Comment: have you tried calling it with `index=True` or do you specifically want to avoid making the DF's index the DB index as well

Comment: have you tried calling it with `index=True` or do you specifically want to avoid making the DF's index the DB index as well

Comment: actually my rows are index now.

Comment: tried with bot `index= True` and `index=False`,till same error.

Comment: for me `dataframe.index.name=None`, is this the problem?

Comment: Oh, that might be a problem. Why not assign a column as an index or reset the index `dataframe.reset-index()` on a small dataframe and see how that behaves.

Comment: *`dataframe.reset_index(drop=True)`