# Pandas create new dataframe from existing dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have an following dataframe

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6
A               q       12             12/5/2018
B               w       13             12/6/2018
C               e       15             12/7/2018
D               r       12             12/8/2018
E               t       18             12/9/2018
F               y       19             12/10/2018
G               u       21             12/5/2018
```

`col2` and `col5` contains `NaN`.

If I do `df.index.values` it's showing `[1 2 3 ..7]`.

So, I am trying to create new dataframe having index as column name as follows:

```
new_dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(data=df,index['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6'])
```

It's working fine but when I do `new_dataframe.index.name` it's `None` and `new_dataframe.index.values` is still `[1 2 3 ..7]`

How do I make index of new_dataframe to be `'col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6'` ?

Comment: i'm not sure what is your expected output, can you update the question with your desired output.

Comment: @HaleemurAli,Check last line of question

Comment: that doesn't makes sense, the dataframe has 7 rows, and your desired index has 6 values.

Comment: That is what, I want make column as index not rows.

Comment: do you want to transpose the dataframe, then you just need to do `df.T`

Comment: It will change my whole dataframe,Isn't it?

Comment: I think it would be clearer if you pasted the expected new data frame in full (with the index)

Comment: brother new_dataframe looks same , but not having changed indices.

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare if you pass an indexed dataframe into the Dataframe constuctor it will consider the index of the dataframe so better consider only the values i.e  `new_dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(data=df.values,index['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6'])`

Comment: And @PiyushS.Wanare why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Dark, All this is for `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50503934/pandas-to-sql-error-invalid-column-name-none?noredirect=1#comment88032161_50503934`